# Move file to specific path in PHP

Tags: php, file

I'm building a web app with MySQL/PHP/JS.

I have files in `htdocs/mywebsite/foo/foo1/` path. Example:

```
htdocs/mywebsite/foo/foo1/image.png
```

I need to move these files to:

```
htdocs/mywebsite/foo3/image.png
```

Any help?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stackoverflow, please follow the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) on how to ask a question... Also, please take a look at [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You ask how to move a file in the file system? I suggest you give the `mv` command a try. `man mv` for the man page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `rename()` function in PHP that will just rename a file or will move it from one directory to another if the from and to directories are different.

```
<?php
    rename("htdocs/mywebsite/foo/foo1/image.png", 
           "htdocs/mywebsite/foo3/image.png");
?>
```

Comment: Yes I already used that but it gives an error saying it can't find the path specified.

Comment: Then check you paths and or the privilages that your web server account has on both paths

Answer (score 0):

In order to move files on a fileserver you need to use FTP (File Transfer Protocol). Programs like FileZilla could help you with that. A proper webhost should also have a FTP client on the control panel.

Using FileZilla:
Login to your webserver, simply cut and paste or drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to simple move all files from FTP using FTP tools like filezila or many other FTP software.

second from putty use mv command to move file.